# Is it normal that my program needs admin rights even to open a file?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-7, rights

When I install my .NET program to C:\Program Files and I run it, it doesn't ask for Admin Rights (Win7), but it can't open any file in the application's directory unless I give admin rights to it manually. If it's not on C, it works well.

I know I can add a custom manifest file to my application to ask the user for admin rights, but it'd ask it always, even when it's not required.

I read on SO that that the software shouldn't write anything to Program Files after it has been installed, but it can't even read a file (for example, language files). I have a database file too, which is read and written by the program, so where should I place this file?

So I'm wondering if it is normal not to have access to read a file without admin rights. How can I make the program ask for admin rights only if it's necessary?

**EDIT** I'm logged on as system admin.

Comment: Can you re-check the read part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal User does not have write privileges in the Progrem Files folder. You should be able to read (content) files however. How do you open you for-reading files?

The proper way is to use a designated folder. Using WinForms that would be something like

```
string dataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(
      Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Comment: A user with admin rights doesn't have write privileges either, UAC exists because everybody got to be an admin.

Comment: You were right, the thirdparty stuff opens the file with read/write permissions even if I don't want to save the file. So that confused me. The ApplicationData folder seems to be good, but for per-user settings. I'd like to store - for example, my database file - globally, so that this is the same for all users. Is it good to store these in "All users" documents?

Comment: @Kisga `SpecialFolder` is an enum with lots of options. Look them up.